# Haskell:Check if first element in a list is a duplicate

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am writing a recursive function called `threeN` that takes a list with one element and adds a new number depending on if it's even or odd. If it's even divide it by 2, and if it's odd multiply it by three and subtract 1. I'm having trouble with my base case which will check the list to see if an element is already contained in the list.

It should be like this:

```
prelude> threeN [9]
[14,5,10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]
```

But Instead I get this:

```
prelude> threeN [9]
[9]
```

This is my code so far:

```
threeN :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
threeN [] = []
threeN [n]
    | n `elem` [n] = [n]
    | n `mod` 2 ==0 = threeN[n `div` 2] ++ [n]
    | n `mod` 2 ==1 = threeN[(3*n)-1] ++ [n]
```

This is supposed to be done with basic functions, so I can't use very advanced ones to solve the issue, which is why I'm having trouble.

Comment: Your code matches the line `9 \`elem\` [9] = [9]` so it just returns `[9]`

Comment: I realized this is the issue but the trouble im having is coming up with a comparison that won’t return the beginning of the function.

Comment: How does the description of the intended behaviour relate to the example? The example looks like it's using the output from one step as input to the next step, but if that's the case, why does it stop after 12 iterations?

Comment: @MarkSeemann The example stops at 12 iterations since the front of the list (14) had already occurred once in the list.

Comment: Why is the second to last element in the example list `26` instead of `28`? `9` is odd, so `9*3+1=28`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`threeN` consumes a list: `xs`, starting with a single element in it. It produces a new element: `x'` based on the value of the head: `x` of `xs`; it prepends `x'` to `xs` if `x'` hasn't occurred in `xs`.

```
threeN :: [Int] -> [Int]
threeN []          = []
threeN l@(x:xs) 
    | x' `elem` l  = l                      -- base case
    | otherwise    = threeN (x':l)
    where
      x' =  if even x then x `div` 2 else x * 3 - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if you can only use basic functions, it still helps if you can decompose the problem into smaller problems. Based on the OP and the comments thread, it seems that these three requirements must be fulfilled:

- Calculate a number based on a previous number
- Generate a list where the next element is based on the previous element
- Stop generating when a duplicate is encountered

I'd suggest solving each of these problems independently of each other, and then combining the solutions.

## Calculate the next number

At first glance, this seems to be the heart of the problem. This is where you need to detect whether the number is even or odd, and calculate a result accordingly. Implement this as a function that you could call, say, `calcNext`. It needs to have a type like this:

```
Prelude> :t calcNext
calcNext :: Integral a => a -> a
```

With it, you can calculate the next number based on any input:

```
Prelude> calcNext 9 
26
Prelude> calcNext 26
13
Prelude> calcNext 13
38
Prelude> calcNext 38
19
```

I'll leave the implementation of `calcNext` as an exercise.

## Generate a list

Sometimes, it can be helpful to look for existing functions. Perhaps there's already a function that can be used to generate a list from a function like `calcNext`.

One way to look for such functions is to use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Making a guess and typing `(a -> a) -> [a]` into the search field on Hoogle yields a number of results, among which is `iterate`, which has the similar (but not identical) type of `(a -> a) -> a -> [a]`. That seems to be close enough, because it enables you to kick off list generation like this:

```
Prelude> take 10 $ iterate calcNext 9
[9,26,13,38,19,56,28,14,7,20]
```

Here I chose to `take 10` because `iterate` will go on forever.

The order here is reversed compared to the OP, but I'll leave it as another exercise to reverse a (finite) list, if the order matters.

If you want to base a solution entirely on functions you wrote yourself, you can try to implement your own `iterate` function. If you need a hint, then you can always peek at the source code of the built-in `iterate` function - it's open source.

## Stop on duplicate

This one is probably the trickiest part, since you need to 'remember' all the previous elements. What you can do is to create a function that not only calculates the next element, but also keeps a list of all previous elements around. You could write a wrapper function around `calcNext` that has a type like this:

```
Prelude> :t calcNextAcc
calcNextAcc :: Integral a => (a, [a]) -> (a, [a])
```

Since this function still returns the same type as its input, you can still use it with `iterate`:

```
Prelude> take 15 $ iterate calcNextAcc (9, [])
[(9,[]),(26,[9]),(13,[26,9]),(38,[13,26,9]),(19,[38,13,26,9]),(56,[19,38,13,26,9]),
 (28,[56,19,38,13,26,9]),(14,[28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),(7,[14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),
 (20,[7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),(10,[20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),
 (5,[10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),(14,[5,10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),
 (7,[14,5,10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),(20,[7,14,5,10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9])]
```

Notice how the second element of each tuple contains all elements calculated so far. Now you just need to go look for duplicates.

You could, for example, write a function called `containsDuplicates` with this type:

```
Prelude> :t containsDuplicates
containsDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

With that, you can use a function like the built-in `takeWhile` to `iterate` until you find a duplicate:

```
Prelude> takeWhile (not . containsDuplicates . snd) $ iterate calcNextAcc (9, [])
[(9,[]),(26,[9]),(13,[26,9]),(38,[13,26,9]),(19,[38,13,26,9]),(56,[19,38,13,26,9]),
 (28,[56,19,38,13,26,9]),(14,[28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),(7,[14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),
 (20,[7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),(10,[20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),
 (5,[10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]),(14,[5,10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9])]
```

The last element there contains your solution:

```
Prelude> last $ takeWhile (not . containsDuplicates . snd) $ iterate calcNextAcc (9, [])
(14,[5,10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9])
```

You can easily turn that tuple into a list:

```
Prelude> uncurry (:) $ last $ takeWhile (not . containsDuplicates . snd) $ iterate calcNextAcc (9, [])
[14,5,10,20,7,14,28,56,19,38,13,26,9]
```

I've left the implementation of the various functions as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Why the signature is `[Integer] -> [Integer]`? the input is actually just a number. The following code works.

```
threeN :: Integer -> [Integer]
threeN n = threeN' n []
  where threeN' n acc 
          | n `elem` acc = n:acc
          | even n = threeN' (n `div` 2) (n:acc)
          | odd n = threeN' (3 * n - 1) (n:acc)
```

If you are force to use `[Integer]` as input signature:

```
threeN :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
threeN [n] = threeN' n []
  where threeN' n acc 
          | n `elem` acc = n:acc
          | even n = threeN' (n `div` 2) (n:acc)
          | odd n = threeN' (3 * n - 1) (n:acc)
```

But I think It does not make sense.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `head` and `tail` with `elem` to test whether the first element already exists in the list. Note however that `head` and `tail` are unsafe functions. They will crash if given an empty list.

```
threeN :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
threeN ns | n `elem` tail ns = ns
          | even n = threeN ([n `div` 2]++ns)
          | odd  n = threeN ([3*n-1]++ns)
  where
    n = head ns
```

Also if you do not want the repeat number to be in the output, then have the first guard just equal `tail ns` instead of `ns`. There is probably a more efficient algorithm to generate these lists, but this just modifies what you've provided.